# Making a list of tuples from prime factorization output for any value?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I turn the resulting tuple into a list of tuples containing the prime numbers and how many times it appers. I've tried `tuples = tuple(2, factors.count(2))` and then doing the same for other numbers and then do `list(zip(list1,list2)` but that would just hard code the output:
E,g

```
In: 288

Out: [(2, 5), (3, 2)]

def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []

    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)

    tuple1 = tuple(factors)
    return tuple1

    

n = int(input())
print(prime_factors(n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `collections.Counter`.

```py
import collections
list(collections.Counter((2,2,2,3,4)).items())
```

gives

```
[(2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```